# One-dimensional scheme with no closed points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Can someone give a reasonably explicit example of an irreducible one-dimensional scheme with no closed points?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg no, I am OK with the axiom of choice (and I am not sure that examples of this spirit depend on it). What I mean is that one could probably give an answer like "take this well-known example of a scheme with no closed point and take the closure of this point", but this closure is not necessarily easy to compute. What I want is fairly concrete presentation of the example.

Comment: Every noetherian topological space has a closed point - just keep taking smaller and smaller closures of points, eventually you will find a closed point. For a one-dimensional scheme, you find that every non-generic point is closed.

Comment: Apologies, I kind of forgot what the definition of noetherian. You only need to assume your space has no infinite descending chains of *irreducible* closed subsets for the argument to work (which follows trivially from finite-dimensionality). Also, as Eric notes in his answer, you need to assume the space is $T_0$ (which schemes always are)

Comment: If this question was interesting enough that an answer received 5 upvotes, then what reasonable grounds do we have for downvoting the question?

Comment: @MarkFischler the question is kind of way too trivial and I am ashamed of having asked it. The proper policy, I believe, is not to give any answers to an off-topic question and to close it asap (and if there any answers, even good ones, to down-vote them to discourage answering off-topic questions). So in this case, down-votes for the question are justified and up-votes for the answer are not, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X$ is a 1-dimensional scheme with no closed points, let $x\in X$ be a point.  Since $x$ is not closed, then there is some point $y\neq x$ in its closure.  Since $y$ is not closed, there is a point $z\neq y$ in its closure.  Now we have a chain $$\overline{\{z\}}\subset\overline{\{y\}}\subset\overline{\{x\}}$$ of irreducible closed subsets.  This contradicts the assumption that $X$ is 1-dimensional.

More generally, the same argument shows any nonempty finite dimensional $T_0$ space has a closed point (the $T_0$ assumption is used to guarantee that the inclusions as above are strict).

Comment: How do you know that $\overline{\{y\}}\subsetneq\overline{\{x\}}$?

Comment: That follows from the fact that $x\neq y$ since any scheme is $T_0$.